# How is get_header() calling a specific PHP file?

Tags: php, wordpress, include, get-headers

I'm trying to learn Wordpress Structure with investigating some free plugins/themes.

I'm working on "Renger Blog Theme" right now, but I couldn't understand something. I've checked **get_header**() page in the WP manual but it still looks like a magic :)

This theme has custom function codes in

```
wordpress\wp-content\themes\renderblog\inc\renderoption.php
```

and this theme calling this file with just

```
get_header();
```

in *index.php*

There is no include code in *header.php* or wherever else.

How it's calling this specific PHP file with `get_header()`? Is it like a way to include automatically all files in the inc folder?

When I just delete `get_header()` from the index.php, the functions are not working.

Comment: Have you already seen https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header?

Comment: Before loading `index.php`, Wordpress loads `functions.php` (of the current theme). So, the logical and the includes are in `functions.php`. Some informations here : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71406/is-there-a-flowchart-for-wordpress-loading-sequence

Comment: @VincentDecaux YES! I'm really a stupid I was knowing the functions are including. Thank u Vincent.

Comment: Also a useful trick can be `grep`ing your code base. `grep -E 'function\s+get_header\(\)' --include="*.php" -r .` from the root of your code base should bring but scripts that define that function.

Answer (score 5):

WordPress `get_header()` is the function predefined by WordPress inbuilt structure. This function Includes the header template for a theme or if a name is specified then a specialized header will be included.

if the file is called "header-new.php" then specify "new".

For example `<?php get_header('new'); ?>`

Another example for Different headers for different pages.

```
<?php
// if detect home page of wordpress
if ( is_home() ) :
    get_header( 'home' );
// if detect Not found page 404 of wordpress
elseif ( is_404() ) :
    get_header( '404' );
// default header if nothing specific is detected
else :
    get_header();
endif;
?>
```